# javascript variable not being passed to hidden input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input as follows:

```
<input class="item_shipval" type="hidden" value="" id="shipvalue">
```

and javascript code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (shipEmpty){
        var shipval = myObject;
        document.getElementById('shipvalue').value = shipval;
    }
    else {
        var shipval = "Registered_Air_Mail";
        document.getElementById('shipvalue').value = shipval;
    }
    //console.log (shipval);
</script>
```

Console.log is showing the shipval values fine. But it is not passed to hidden input value with id "shipvalue".

What is wrong with the code above ? Thanks in advance. I am a javascript newbie..

Comment: put the code inside `window.onLoad` or place the script tag after all the elements.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy  Sorry, i am unable to understand. Please note that I am a javascript beginner

Comment: Make sure that your JavaScript is place below your HTML on you page. Generally you want it right before the closing `</body>` tag. And/or place your code inside of window.onload...`window.onload = function() {
    // your code goes here
}
`
This way your code is run after all the HTML has be loaded.

Comment: @user3790186 I don't think there's enough information here to diagnose the problem. What is `shipEmpty` and where is `myObject` defined? Also, where is the script on the page in relation to your hidden input?

Comment: You should not define same variable twice as you did "var shipval" in if and else part.

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar var shipval1 and var shipval2 did not help ??

Comment: @user3790186, see my answer where I defined variable at single place and changing its value inside if condition. try like that..

Comment: @RGraham shipEmpty and  myObject values are being passed and console.log gives correct results

Comment: @user3790186 It's all well and good talking about this in the comments, but you should *prove it*. Add *all relevant code* to the question and if possible, give a reproducable example in something like jsFiddle

Comment: @user3790186, please make sure that you got only one HTML element iwht id="shipvalue", otherwise document.getElementById will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Make your code something like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<input class="item_shipval" type="hidden" value=""  id="shipvalue">

<script type="text/javascript">

    if (shipEmpty){
        var shipval = myObject;
        document.getElementById('shipvalue').value = shipval;
    }
    else {
        var shipval = "Registered_Air_Mail";
        document.getElementById('shipvalue').value = shipval;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code is same...but you are facing the problem because you may have given the javascript above the input tag. I don't know what this shipEmpty & myObject is...but I tried with this code giving dumy values to both these variables & was able to get results without any error. shipval variable was passed to the hidden field. @user3790186

Answer (score 1):

Try this : using jQuery you can set value of hidden variable provided that you should include jquery library in your html before using it (see below code). Also `document.ready` will ensure that jQuery will execute only after loading all DOM structure.

**NOTE** - Assuming myObject is defined already.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var shipval = "Registered_Air_Mail";
    if (shipEmpty){
        shipval = myObject;
    }

    $('#shipvalue').val(shipval);

    console.log (shipval);
});
</script>
```

**EDIT** : - remove duplicate declaration of `shipval` variable in javascript code like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var shipval = "Registered_Air_Mail"; // give some default value
    if (shipEmpty){
        shipval = myObject; // change value if condition is true
    }

    document.getElementById('shipvalue').value = shipval;

    console.log (shipval);
</script>
```

Comment: Console.log as before is providing correct values. But it is not passed to hidden input value..That is the issue ??

Comment: @user3790186, could `myObject` be the issue? Maybe replace `shipval = myObject;` with `shipval = 'foo';` to make sure.

Comment: Issue could be that you are calling javascript before loading input hidden element, thats why I keep the script inside document.ready. And I declaring same variable twice causing problem, as console.log don't know which one to refer. Try your code by defining single variable.

Comment: @jared_flack Provided shipval = "foo" and still not being passed

Comment: @user3790186, see my edit in answer. Use same code and try. Also make sure that you have only one html element with id="shipvalue"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your JavaScript is placed below your HTML on you page. That way when your JS tries to `getElementById`, the element actually exists on the page. Generally you want your JS included right before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- HTML goes first -->
<input class="item_shipval" type="hidden" value="" id="shipvalue">
<!-- JavaScript goes after -->
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var shipval;
        if (shipEmpty){
            shipval = myObject;
            document.getElementById('shipvalue').value = shipval;
        }
        else {
            shipval = "Registered_Air_Mail";
            document.getElementById('shipvalue').value = shipval;
        }
        // console.log (shipval);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/7EZ4Z/.

If you set `shipEmpty` to true or false, both work.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you put it if you wrap it in window.onload as you did above.

Comment: @JustinPaulson Correct, but it's still a good practice (in my opinion). I've had weird stuff happen when I don't.

Comment: It is really a personal preference at that point.  I like to have all my script tags in the head of the file.